# Is wordpress + Fullpage.js horizontal scroll possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, fullpage.js

Been playing around with Fullpage.js (http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)and wordpress, which has been pretty successful. The script, which is great, uses a htmlstructure where divs inside a slidecontainer becomes horizontal slides.

For wordpress i have a loop that fetches pages to become slides, and that works well. However, to create pages that are being placed inside a parent container with the right class seems to be something i just cant figure out. Does feel like it should be possible though? If anyone has any idea of a loop that can do what i want, i would be grateful for any advise.

`

```
<?php

   if (($locations = get_nav_menu_locations()) && $locations['main-nav'] ) {
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations['main-nav'] );
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
    $pageID = array();
    foreach($menu_items as $item) {
        if($item->object == 'page')
            $pageID[] = $item->object_id;
    }
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'page','post__in' => $pageID, 'posts_per_page' => count($pageID), 'orderby' => 'post__in' ) );
    }
    while(have_posts() ) : the_post();

    ?> 


   <!--     <div id="<?php echo $post->post_name;?>" class="section"> -->
 <div id="content2">
    <div id="pageSlide-<?php echo $post->post_name;?>" class="section" data-anchor="<?php echo $post->post_name;?>">

    <div id="content">

        <div id="inner-content" class="wrap clearfix">

            <div id="main" class="twelvecol first clearfix" role="main">

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'clearfix' ); ?> role="article" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

                            <header class="article-header">

                                <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                            </header>

                            <section class="entry-content clearfix" itemprop="articleBody">
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </section>

                            <footer class="article-footer">
                                <p class="clearfix"><?php the_tags( '<span class="tags">' . __( 'Tags:', 'bonestheme' ) . '</span> ', ', ', '' ); ?></p>

                            </footer>

                </article>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

```
  </div> <!-- end of page div-->

 ?php endwhile;?> <!-- end of query -->
```

`

Comment: should definitely be possible. show us your code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Added my loop to the question. Im using a custom walker and anchorlinks to create the slides.